# Nativescript: any way to animate ListView item height?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript

I would like to animate ListView item height on tap that it would expand. Currently NativeScript doesn't support animation of height property.

I found this solution:

http://nuvious.com/Blog/2017/8/4/is-it-possible-to-animate-height-and-width-in-nativescript-yes

Although it works perfectly with any other View it doesn't work for ListView item (animation doesn't happen).

I hope there might be any native iOS and Android solutions that I can adapt for my needs or something else.

Comment: I have a little zoom-effect on my ListView items. Would that work for you?

Comment: Do you mean using scale animation? I'm using templates for different ListView item states. When an item is tapped it gets "active" and its template is different and approx. twice higher in height than the "standard" ListView item. What I'm trying to accomplish is to show kind of expanding animation to grow from standard ListView item to active one on tap.

Comment: Ah OK, that doesn't sound like what I'm using so I won't bother you with that.